# groovy multiline string escape all

Tags: groovy

I have a groovy string like this:

```
String test = 

"""     
abc{ der}
token: "\330\272%\006\272W\264\000T\226\022[\310\2207#fs\032q"      
""";
```

However groovy is printing out like "Øº%ºW". How can I make it to print out exactly like the above string. I don't want to escape the \.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is the tripple slashy string, which doesn't exist (yet?)

You might try:

```
String token = /\330\272%\006\272W\264\000T\226\022[\310\2207#fs\032q/
String test = """
abc{ der}
token: "${token}"
"""
```

Update! Now in Groovy 1.8, the slashy string is multiline. This should work:

```
String test = /
abc{ der}
token: "\330\272%\006\272W\264\000T\226\022[\310\2207#fs\032q"
/
```

See: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+1.8+release+notes#Groovy1.8releasenotes-Slashystrings

Comment: i really don't want to modify anything inside the """ ... """. I used to read it from a file in java and I was hoping for a way to declare it directly from my groovy code.

Comment: You can either escape your escapes """\\""" or use slashy strings /bl\3567ah/ but slashy strings can't have newlines in them. Yet.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
String test = """
abc{ der}
token: "${/\330\272%\006\272W\264\000T\226\022[\310\2207#fs\032q/}"
"""
```

Any String that is enclosed by forward-slashes (/) does not need to have the backslashes () escaped.

Answer (score 0):

This would work, testing in Groovy 2.4.xx

```
def testMultiLine = $/
test
test1
test2
/$
```